# Join dataframes - one with multiindex columns and the other without

Tags: python, pandas, join, multi-index

I'm trying to join two dataframes - one with multiindex columns and the other with a single column name. They have similar index.

I get the following warning:

> "UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (3 levels on the left, 1 on the right)"

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

np.random.seed(2022)  # so the data is the same each time
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3), index=['A', 'B', 'C'],columns=['w'])

df3 = df.join(df2)
```

### DataFrame Views

#### `df`

```
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux          
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A      -0.000528 -0.274901 -0.139286  1.984686  0.282109  0.760809  0.300982  0.540297
B       0.373497  0.377813 -0.090213 -2.305943  1.142760 -1.535654 -0.863752  1.016545
C       1.033964 -0.824492  0.018905 -0.383344 -0.304185  0.997292 -0.127274 -1.475886
```

#### `df2`

```
          w
A -1.940906
B  0.833649
C -0.567218
```

#### `df3` - Result

```py
   (bar, one)  (bar, two)  (baz, one)  (baz, two)  (foo, one)  (foo, two)  (qux, one)  (qux, two)         w
A   -0.000528   -0.274901   -0.139286    1.984686    0.282109    0.760809    0.300982    0.540297 -1.940906
B    0.373497    0.377813   -0.090213   -2.305943    1.142760   -1.535654   -0.863752    1.016545  0.833649
C    1.033964   -0.824492    0.018905   -0.383344   -0.304185    0.997292   -0.127274   -1.475886 -0.567218
```

---

- `df.join(df2)` from [`pandas v1.3.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#other-deprecations) results in a `FutureWarning`

  - `FutureWarning: merging between different levels is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right) df3 = df.join(df2)`.

What is the best way to join these two dataframes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on what you want!  Do you want the column from `df2` to be aligned with the 1st or second level of columns from `df`?

You have to add a level to the columns of `df2`

Super cheezy with `pd.concat`

```
df.join(pd.concat([df2], axis=1, keys=['a']))
```

Better way

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a'], df2.columns])

df.join(df2)
```

[image]

Comment: How did you create that table graphic?

Comment: Results in `FutureWarning: merging between different levels is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.`. Maybe update the answer please.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is to convert `df2` to `MultiIndex`, and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','w')])
print (df2)
          a
          w
A -1.940906
B  0.833649
C -0.567218
```

Or:

```
df2.columns = [['a'], df2.columns]
print (df2)
          a
          w
A -1.940906
B  0.833649
C -0.567218
```

---

```
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df3 = df.join(df2)
```

Result:

```
print (df3)
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux                   a
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two         w
A      -0.000528 -0.274901 -0.139286  1.984686  0.282109  0.760809  0.300982  0.540297 -1.940906
B       0.373497  0.377813 -0.090213 -2.305943  1.142760 -1.535654 -0.863752  1.016545  0.833649
C       1.033964 -0.824492  0.018905 -0.383344 -0.304185  0.997292 -0.127274 -1.475886 -0.567218
```

### Additional Resources

- [pandas docs: Joining a single Index to a MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#joining-a-single-index-to-a-multiindex)
- [pandas docs: Joining with two MultiIndexes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#joining-with-two-multiindexes)