# pandas dataframe merge merging between different levels can give an unintended result

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am doing a left join between two dataframes right and left using `merge`:

```
left.merge(right, on='A', how='left')
```

I get the warning

```
UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right)
```

But if I do
`right.index.nlevels` and `left.index.nlevels` I get 1 for both.

should i ignore that warning?

Note: if I get the index of both I get:

```
>>> left = mshareFrame
>>> right.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=138, step=1)
>>> left.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2114906, step=1)
>>> x = left.merge(right, on='isin', how='left')
C:\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:618: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
```

Comment: I would love to see your dataframes,  I have a hunch that one has a multi-index and the other one does not.  It would be better if they both had the same index.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223615/join-dataframes-one-with-multiindex-columns-and-the-other-without

Comment: I don't think I can share the data, (proprietary). But if I do this
   >>> left = mshareFrame
   >>> right.index
   RangeIndex(start=0, stop=138, step=1)
   >>> left.index
   RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2114906, step=1)
   >>> x = left.merge(right, on='isin', how='left')
  C:\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:618: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)