# Unable to merge on pivoted data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pivot-table

This is my pivoted data which is in df1

|  | Sales |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type | amount | country |
| name |  |  |
| aa | 200 | ind |
| bb | 300 | aus |
| cc | 400 | sa |
| dd | 500 | fra |

This is my second dataframe df2

| name | amount | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 500 | ind |
| bb | 600 | aus |
| cc | 700 | sa |
| dd | 800 | fra |

I am trying to do a merge like

```
merge1=pd.merge(df2,df1, on='name', how='left')
```

Although it executes successfully, I get the below warning. I want this to be removed.

D:\Python_Pandsas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:648: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left,2 on the right)
warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join dataframes - one with multiindex columns and the other without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223615/join-dataframes-one-with-multiindex-columns-and-the-other-without)

Comment: I had seen the solution before but was not getting it Was trying to understand the concept of join and concat. I came to know about reset_index which solved my problem